# Differences between up and back button in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a basic "Find my nearest..." application as a learning exercise.

I have 3 activities:

1. A main activity, where the user enters his address, this passes an
   array of objects to the list activity via the intent.
2. A list activity, which shows the nearest 10 places. When an item is selected this passes an object to the detail activity via the intent.
3. A detail activity, showing the detail for the selected place.

I have most things working, however I have noticed a slight problem, arising the difference from the back button (at the bottom of my phone screen), and the up button (the on action bar). After researching the difference between the two, it would appear they should behave the same in this scenario. When hitting the back button, everything works as intended, and we still see the same list. However, when hitting the up button, it appears to startup / resume the list activity in a different way, and the data from the list has disappeared.

Would anyone be able to explain to me why this is happening and how to prevent it?

My code is below: (any criticisms about my Android / Java techniques are very welcome!)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String TRACKS = "com.example.firstapp.TRACKS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the 'Search' button */
    public void search(View view) {

        // Get Address Text
        // EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_address);
        // String address = editText.getText().toString();

        // Get tracks near to address
        Track[] trackArray = new Track[20];

        for(int i=0; i < trackArray.length; i++) {
            trackArray[i] = new Track("Track " + i, "Address" + i, (float) Math.random()*10);
        }

        // Fire intent to show results
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TRACKS, trackArray);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

TrackListActivity.java

```
public class TrackListActivity extends ListActivity {

    public final static String TRACK = "com.mycroft.runtrackdir.TRACK";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent.hasExtra(MainActivity.TRACKS)) {
            Parcelable[] tempTrackArray = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.TRACKS);        

            // Cast Parcelable to Track
            Track[] trackArray = new Track[tempTrackArray.length];
            for(int i=0; i < trackArray.length; i++) {
                trackArray[i] = (Track) tempTrackArray[i];
            }

            ArrayAdapter<Track> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Track>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, trackArray);
            setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Track clickedTrack = (Track) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

        // Fire intent to show detail
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TRACK, clickedTrack);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

TrackDetailActivity.java

```
public class TrackDetailActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Track track = intent.getParcelableExtra(TrackListActivity.TRACK);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_detail);

        TextView track_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track_name);
        TextView track_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track_address);
        TextView track_distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track_distance);

        track_name.setText(track.name);
        track_address.setText(track.address);
        track_distance.setText(track.distance.toString());

    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.firstapp.TrackListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_track_list"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.firstapp.TrackDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_track_detail"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.firstapp.TrackListActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.firstapp.TrackListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should modify your `Manifest.xml` file and tell your `Manifest file` the relationships between your activities. This should solve the problem.

For Example:

```
<application ... >
...
<!-- The main/home activity (has no parent activity) -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>
<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

You can also review [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) document.

**EDIT:**
You can also use Data Persistence, if you are receiving empty Intents in certain Activities.
for Data persistence in Android, you can use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), [Serialization](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html), etc

As you are learning Android Development, you can simply put the `trackArray` values in Shared Preferences of your application while starting List Activity from Main Activity and Load the data of `trackArray` from Shared Preferences in List Activity in `onResume` and populate it in `onCreate`.
This way, your Action bar's up button will not make the data of ListView Activity disappear.

P.S: Shared pref's actual purpose is to store values that are less in size and are changed occasionally such as Setting's data of a specific Application. Therefore, please don't misuse it.

Comment: This list activity has the main activity as it's parent. And the detail activity has the list activity as it's parent. This is how it should be isn't it? I'll add my manifest file to the original post.

Comment: I think your List activity's `onCreate` or `onResume` is being called when up button in Action bar is pressed, therefore the List Activity is receiving an empty intent and not populating the data.

Comment: You can verify my diagnosis, by putting a Log and check if the `onCreate` and `onResume` is being called in List Activity when the Action-bar's back Button is being pressed.

Comment: Hi @salman, thanks for your help. You are correct, when the back button is pressed, just `onResume` is called, but when the up button is pressed both `onCreate` and `onResume` are called resulting in my current situation. Your edited answer seems to be ambiguous, first you suggest to use Shared Pref's, then mention this is bad practice. Is there no better solution?

I found that altering the default behaviour of the home button fixed my problem, by calling `finish` in the detail activity when home is pressed. Is this bad practice or a viable solution?

Comment: @user2665900 i asked you to use Shared Prefs temporarily as it will give you a taste of data persistence in Android development. Altering the default behavior of Home button and finishing your current activity when it is clicked is not a bad practice. But, in the long run, i recommend you to go for Data persistence (SQLite Database) for managing the queries of your users. As it will help you get rid of worries regarding data loss during activity switching and help you further enhance the app's features by including user's search history and other related data.

Answer (score 1):

- ### Difference between Up Button and Back Button.

Back Button- Back Button takes you to the last activity where you are previously active.

Up button- Up Button takes you one level up in hierarchical or ancestral way.No matter what is your last active activity,you will always be redirected towards the parent activity that you have set in the manifest.

> Although Back and Up Button almost does the same thing in many
>   conditions but they were doing whole different steps behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Add  launchMode = “singleTop” to your TrackListActivity in the manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.TrackListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_track_list"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

you need to use launchMode="singleTop" if you don’t want your Activity killed and restarted when the Up button is pressed.